# write-back cache policy in a multilevel cache and bandwidth between different level caches

Tags: caching, memory, x86, processor, cpu-cache

When my professor taught us how write-back cache policy worked, the examples were always on a unicore system with one cache level, so (using write-back policy) he told us that in a block replacement with dirty bit == 1 the block needed to be copied in main memory. But my question is: In a real case of multilevel caches and a multicore system is that true? I mean, **if a block which has dirty bit == 1 is replaced from my L1 cache, is it *only* copied to main memory?** **or is it copied to the upper cache level (mantaining D==1) but not copied to memory?** **Or both of them (copied to all upper cache levels + copied to main memory)?** (on this last case I assume that, in upper cache levels, the block is copied with D==0 since the block is already updated in main memory).

And also **I want to add a question: the copy of one memory block from one level cache to another level cache (supose 64 Bytes blocks) can be done in one cicle (generally in modern processor)?** or there is not such a wide bandwidth to do this in just one cycle?

If the answer to the first paragraph depends on if we have an inclusive or an exclusive cache policy, answer for both cases please

Comment: Write-back can stop at L2 or L3, otherwise memset performance would completely fall off a cliff once you passed L1d size, and you can see from benchmarks that doesn't happen.  Note that MESI cache coherency is usually discussed for single-level caches that are all siblings, not parent/child.  Real systems are both multi-core and multi-level, making everything more complicated.

Comment: So in write-back cache, if a L1d block with DB == 1 is evicted, it is copied to L2 and L3 but not to memory. Wow, i didn't imagine that. And the block copy can be done in 1 cycle or the bandwidth between caches is not that wide?

Comment: No, it's first written back to L2.  It's only written back to L3 when it's eventually evicted from L2, which might be after overwriting L2 several more times.  (And shared L3 can be the backstop for data shared between cores, not RAM).  Modern x86 can transfer a full line at once, but bandwidth is limited to less than 1 full line / clock by how many in-flight transfers a core can track between L1d and L2. (Writes need RFO and write back, but even reads aren't 1/clock)  See also https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/software-tuning-performance-optimization-platform-monitoring/topic/801995

Comment: But yes, the connection between L1d and L2 is 64 bytes wide (full line), since Haswell for Intel: https://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/5/.  However, Skylake still improved L2 bandwidth at least for the case where you're only actually reading one load per line, not both 32-byte halves for example.  @BeeonRope did some testing: https://github.com/travisdowns/uarch-bench/wiki/How-much-bandwidth-does-the-L2-have-to-give,-anyway%3F

Comment: But I have found here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_hierarchy) that says: "in the case of the write back policy, the changed cache block will be updated in the lower-level hierarchy only when the cache block is evicted. A "dirty bit" is attached to each cache block and set whenever the cache block is modified. During eviction, blocks with a set dirty bit will be written to the lower-level hierarchy.". I think that this is contradicting what you said, because they say that, in write back policy (in an eviction of a block with DB==1), the lower-level hierarchy (main memory) is written!

Comment: Are they wrong? or didn't I understand what you said? @PeterCordes

Comment: You misinterpreted what wikipedia is saying.  They said "lowER", i.e. the next level outwards, not the lowEST (main memory).  e.g. write-back of a dirty line from L2 creates a dirty line in L3, which itself will be written back at some point.  (Or read by another core without having been written back yet).

Comment: That's true, I misinterpreted that! Now I am reading what @BeeonRope sais in the link you gave me but there is a thing that I cannot understand: How is it possible 81Bytes/cicle of sustained bandwidth in L1d? As far as I understand, most programs have stores and loads of variables of 4 or 8 bytes length,**how is it possible to almost get the 32B load + 32B load + 32B store that L1d is able to get?** I thought the normal thing would be something like 4B + 4B + 4B

Comment: 32-byte SIMD load/store with AVX.  Intel since Haswell has 32-byte datapaths in the load/store execution units.  (64-byte wide in Skylake-X with AVX512.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I was thinking again about what we discussed about cache bandwidth and one doubt has invaded me: In modern processors, L2 caches are divided into banks / slices (like L3) so that L1i and L1d cache can make simultaneous accesses to two different banks of L2?? If so, why in the link you showed me the peak bandwidth of L2 is only 64Bytes instead of >64??

Comment: I was talking only talking about L2 <-> L1d bandwidth, assuming L1i or uop-cache hits.  It's probably very rare for both L1i and L1d to max out their L2 access bandwidth. The main other demand on L2 is receiving lines from L3 (including requests made by HW prefetchers, L2 streamer and spatial prefetcher).  L2 isn't distributed between cores like L3 slices; each core has *its own* private L2 cache.  The don't form a large shared cache, they're fully separate.  Also, I doubt that its banked in the same way Sandybridge L1d was; a read always needs to read the full line.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if L2 does only have 1 read port, though, that L1i and L1d have to compete for.  With L1d barely able to saturate it, and not when the core does load both halves, it's probably barely a slowdown if the occasional instruction-fetch from L1i takes priority.  There might be multiple ports total so data arriving for HW prefetch and L2 demand misses don't steal too much bandwidth from L1d miss demand loads.